# Semaphore synchronization method to create a file python

Tags: python, multithreading

Good night companions, I must implement a program that does the following, use the semaphore synchronization method to create a file containing the primes stored in the files, the files have the following structure:

`526,850,110,939,945,922,405,975,477,298`

The program should create a thread for each of the files and store the primes at the same time in a single file called primes.txt

I have already stored all the cousins, but when I write the final file with all the cousins, only some of them appear, not all of the stored ones in self.primes.

```
import threading 
from threading import *
import time

sema = threading.Semaphore()

class ProcessPrimes(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, name,file):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.file = file
        self.primes = []
        self.count_primes = 0
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        
    
    def run(self):
        sema.acquire()
        print("Start")
        with open(self.file, "r") as filestream:
            for line in filestream:
                currentline = line.split(",")
                line = currentline.pop()
                int_list = list(map(int, currentline))
               #print(int_list)
          
            for num in int_list:
                c_div = 0
                for x in range(2,num):
                    if(num%x == 0):
                        c_div += 1
                        break
                if(c_div == 0):
                    #es primo
                    self.count_primes += 1
                    self.primes.append(num)
                    
            print(self.name,"---->",self.count_primes, "primes") 
            print(self.primes)
            
            #Write final file
            writeFile("finalFile.txt", self.primes)   
            sema.release()
            
    def getprime(self):
        return self.primes
    

def writeFile(name,string):
    file = open(name,'w')
    file.write(str(string))
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    
                
def main():
    
    process = []
    for j in range(10):
            prc = ProcessPrimes("Thread"+str(j),"testFile_"+str(j)+".txt")
            process.append(prc)
            
    for prc in process:
            prc.start()
                
    for prc in process:
            prc.join()
        
   
main()
```

If I am using the semaphore method correctly?, I am a bit new to this and I am not able to store all the primes shown on the screen

[image]

only the primes of the last thread are stored.

Comment: `open(name,'w')` overwrites the file every time you open it. Do you want to open it for appending? Then use `open(name,'a')`

Comment: thank you very much that solved that problem for me, I needed to fix the synchronization but I already managed to configure the traffic lights too